# Need guidance on Introduction to Spring JMS Active MQ

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am following ["I coding blog"](http://icodingclub.blogspot.com/2011/07/introduction-of-spring-jms-with.html) which is very good for someone like me who wants to get into Spring, JMS and ActiveMQ.

When I run  TestJMSListener  as a java application, I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main"    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/jms/helloworld/config/JMSConfig.xml]: Error setting property values;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'brokerurl' of bean class [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory]: 
Bean property 'brokerurl' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. 
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I do not know how to fix it, below is my JMSConfig.xml file:

```
your xml file here.
```

Comment: Copy&Paste JMSConfig.xml file in your question

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.html#brokerURL) the property is called `brokerURL`, not `brokerurl`. Spring helpfully reported the cause of the problem in the exception message.